# Chrome browser does not show a position:'fixed' bottom:'0' until after a refresh

Tags: css, reactjs, node.js, typescript, vite

In Mobile Chrome browsers the div at the bottom only renders if the page is moved/refreshed. Once this happens it works great and works after it's cached. However, the first time you open the page ('I use incognito mode so nothing is cached') it just isn't visible.

Also on Mobile Firefox, this div has to adjust its position when the URL bar disappears to be anchored on the bottom again, creating a janky look. However, on Firefox it renders right away every time.

Anchoring to the top works just great on all browsers. Exact same code.
My React front end is in a Docker container, I am using Node.js, Vite.js, and React. I am developing locally.

I have spent many hours trying to figure this out and can't find a solution. Any help would be great! thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module">import { injectIntoGlobalHook } from "/@react-refresh";
injectIntoGlobalHook(window);
window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {};
window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type;</script>

    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx?t=1707096700138"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
lang-jsx
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
          <div style={{
  position: 'sticky',
  top: 0,
  minWidth: '100%', 
}}>Header</div>

<div style={{
  minWidth: '100%', 
  minHeight: '100vh',
}}>SOME CONTENT</div>

<div style={{
  minWidth: '100%', 
  minHeight: '100vh', 
}}>SOME CONTENT</div>

<div style={{
  position: 'fixed',
  bottom: 0,
  minWidth: '100%',
}}>Footer</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```css
#root {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .logo {
    height: 6em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    will-change: filter;
    transition: filter 300ms;
  }
  .logo:hover {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #646cffaa);
  }
  .logo.react:hover {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #61dafbaa);
  }
  
  @keyframes logo-spin {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  @media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    a:nth-of-type(2) .logo {
      animation: logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
    }
  }
  
  .card {
    padding: 2em;
  }
  
  .read-the-docs {
    color: #888;
  }
```

I have tried using animations, sticky, and zzz. It doesn't show in developer tools on a desktop so I ran into this issue in the middle of making a UI. Because I couldn't find a solution I stripped the app down to its bare parts and the issue is still occurring.

Comment: Welcome! Please post your rendered HTML and give us the minimal amount of HTML to reproduce. It's really hard to debug components without seeing how the content is rendered in context.

Answer (score -2):

After trying many different things and starting with the very basic install and 4 divs I figured out the issue. I wasn't letting the chrome browser fully load before I went to my site. If I  wait 1-2 seconds the bottom bar would load fine.